# How to return an array where a column matches a value

Tags: arrays, excel, return, match, vlookup

I am trying to create the column _Type_below which return the type value for a matching name AND a matching interval. I know I can use VLOOKUP for individual names, but lets say I have thousands of names and I can specify an array for VLOOKUP for all of them. Cheers!!

```
Name   position             _Type_             Name    Range_From      Range_To     Type
bob    0                      A                bob     0               30            A
bob    5                      A                bob     30              100           B
bob    10                     A                doug    0               40            C
bob    15                     A                doug    40              200           A
bob    20                     A
bob    30                     B
bob    40                     B
bob    80                     B
doug   0                      C
doug   20                     C
doug   40                     A
...
```

Comment: what version do you have?

Comment: I am fine with the long processing time

Comment: 365 is my version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If yu have the dynamic array formula you can use FILTER():

```
 =VLOOKUP(B2,FILTER(E:G,A2=D:D),3)
```

[image]

---

If not then your data must be sorted on D then E:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,D:D,0)):INDEX(G:G,MATCH(A2,D:D,0)+COUNTIF(D:D,A2)-1),3)
```

This should be relatively quick, but it requires the data sorted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go super old fashioned and get the row using `SumProduct()` and pass that into `Index()`. It's not going to be speedy though.

```
=INDEX($I$1:$I$5, SUMPRODUCT(($F$1:$F$5=A2)*($G$1:$G$5<=B2)*($H$1:$H$5>B2)*ROW($F$1:$F$5)), 1)
```

[image]